# How to center align Ad in windows 8 App

Tags: css, windows-8, windows-8.1

Here is my code to center align Ad in windows 8/8.1 app

```
<div id="myAd" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: auto; width: 728px; height: 90px; z-index: 1"
     data-win-control="MicrosoftNSJS.Advertising.AdControl"
     data-win-options="{applicationId: 'd25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab', adUnitId: '10043105'}">
</div>
```

However i couldn't succeed in aligning.Let's see what you can do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To center a `div` horizontally, use `margin: 0 auto`.

```
<div id="myAd" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; margin: 0 auto; width: 728px; height: 90px; z-index: 1"
     data-win-control="MicrosoftNSJS.Advertising.AdControl"
     data-win-options="{applicationId: 'd25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab', adUnitId: '10043105'}">
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working.It is left aligned.I'm going to try your Construct 2 plugin.Actually i forgot to use it,Just after seeing your profile pic i recall it.Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: LOL. This is a Contruct 2 game? Then, yes, use the plugin! For those reading this thread later, see my plugin here: http://ryanjoy.com/2013/05/introducing-a-windows-store-advertising-plugin-for-scirra-construct-2/

Comment: Yes it is construct 2 game.But plugin is not working as expected for me at-least.What happens is i can add the ads without issue but i made the game in 1920*1080 resolution and if i play the game in a device with 1366*768 resolution the Ad gets cropped off in to a smaller one.However when i play it 1920*1080 resolution it looks fine.Thanks anyways!!!